# Yarn monorepo: run Yarn script on some packages but not all

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to run tests in **SOME** of my workspace packages but **NOT ALL**

From the monorepo root I would like to run something like

```sh
yarn workspaces run test --exclude package3
```

or

```
yarn workspace package1 package2 run test
```

but neither of these commands are valid.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?